# Constructor, loops and arrays practice in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, canvas

I'm trying to make an animation where particles flow from one side the other like a flock of birds. You can see a live version on my semi-finished portfolio here: https://benjamingibbsportfolio.000webhostapp.com/

I'm in the process of learning constructor functions, so I've decided to redo the above project using that type of programming.

I've managed to basically complete it, apart from the fact it only displays one particle/flake - it should show 100?

```
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
     flakes[i] = new Flake();
   }
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Are all the particles simply being drawn at the same place?

I've uploaded the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/q7ja8qxv/

Comment: I don't know — and won't go through your entire code to find out — why it's not working. However, I can tell you that you are using constructors properly.

Comment: `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);` ;)

Comment: Ahh yes thanks! Ive moved that line of code into the drawFlakes function and everything is working perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single flake is drawn with this function:

```
this.display = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffff00";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

The source of the problem is the first line of the function:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
```

This clears the whole canvas...
This means that every flake "erases" the previous flake(s).

As a fix you have to remove the `ctx.clearRect()` call from `Flake.display()` and instead call it in a place where it is only executed once, before you start drawing the flakes. For example in `drawFlakes()` right before the loop:

```
function drawFlakes() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  for (i = 0; i < flakes.length; i++) {
    flakes[i].display();
    flakes[i].move();
    flakes[i].update();
  }

  angle += 0.01;
}
```

Complete example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('stars');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
var flakes = [];
var angle = 0;

canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  flakes[i] = new Flake();
}

function drawFlakes() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  for (i = 0; i < flakes.length; i++) {
    flakes[i].display();
    flakes[i].move();
    flakes[i].update();
  }

  angle += 0.01;
}

function Flake() {
  this.x = Math.random() * w;
  this.y = Math.random() * h;
  this.r = Math.random() * 5 + 2;
  this.d = Math.random() * 1;

  this.display = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffff00";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
  }

  this.move = function() {
    this.y += Math.pow(this.d, 2) + 1;
    this.x += Math.sin(angle) * 60;
  };
  
  this.update = function() {
    if (this.y > h) {
      this.x = Math.random() * w;
      this.y = 0;
      this.r = this.r;
      this.d = this.d;
    }
  };
}

setInterval(drawFlakes, 25);
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="stars"></canvas>
```